# How to restore Texstudio to the configuration before using "latex --shell-escape"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, texstudio, eps, shell-escape

today I implemented (with my Macbook) the answer from: [Export eps figures from TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/export-eps-figures-from-tikz), where I ran the CLI command:

```
latex --shell-escape
```

Up until then I used Texstudio without issues. After that, TexStudio didn't compile most of tex documents. The error was:

```
Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex
```

From tests, I saw that I only could compile tex documents with all the extra files already created (.log, .aux, etc.) I tried many things, like uninstall and install everything (using brew for mactex/texlive/texstudio...) and nothing works.

Is there a way the shell-escape modified some features in a cache file or something similar that overrides new installations and now TexStudio cannot compile new documents?

How can I restore my previous configuration?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: it's highly unlikely to be related to shell escape. tex is not in the path used by your editor, so you have changed the path or previously you called tex by a full file path and now just have local name pdflatex so need the path

Comment: Thanks. I checked the history of my terminal and the only command I wrote was the above one (which was locally invoked in the folder of the file). I did not use a full file path. The strange thing is that afterwards TexStudio stop working for any other file. I restored the paths from TexStudio>Configuration>Build (for any compiler, pdftex,lualatex...) with their default values and nothing improved. By the way, as you mention, how can I check if the tex file is in the path of my editor? I used TexStudio as always, open the tex file with TexStudio and Run&Compile from the editor.

Comment: I don't have texstudio or a Mac, so someone else will answer, but if pdflatex works from the terminal but not from texstudio you have not set the path on the shell used by your desktop

Answer (score 3):

After many tests, I decided to install a previous version ([TexStudio 4.3.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/70d79ca910ac41bf98ad0364801a946becb25250/Casks/texstudio.rb)). Now it runs *"smooth"* as always. It seems that the problem had to do with the new version, in which the **.bst** file needed to be in the same directory. More details on this problem can be found in this post: [Latest version of TexStudio cannot now find the bst file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656619/latest-version-of-texstudio-cannot-now-find-the-bst-file/698098#698098)

I hope it helps to whoever reads this question.